# In MLflow, is there a way group metrics & params into "sections" like the system section?

Tags: python, deep-learning, mlflow

MLFlow has Model metrics and System Metrics tabs (see attached picutres).

I would like to group metrics by loss and evaluation or example. Is it possible to achieve something similar?

[image]
[image]

I've tried different naming styles like "group/metric_name" (system metrics are named like that) but they all end up in the Model Metrics section.

I also tried reading through the code to check what could differentiate but there doesn't seem to be anything related to sections in the mlflow python api. Perhaps it's just the way the UI displays it?